# How to fix PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR when using nginx with ssl?

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I'm trying to reverse-proxy an http server via nginx. The service is listening on port 8123 and I want to proxy it on 443.
I created a self-signed certificate like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Here is the complete nginx configuration:

```
events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        server {
                listen 443 ssl http2;
                listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

                ssl_certificate         /home/mcmsadm/cert.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key     /home/mcmsadm/key.pem;

                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:8123;
                }
        }
}
```

When I try to connect to the server using Firefox, it says PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I found the nginx error message in the logs (Didn't think about it):

```
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/home/mcmsadm/key.pem") failed 
(SSL: error:2807106B:UI routines:UI_process:processing error:while reading strings
error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password 
error:0907B068:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey:bad password read 
error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)
```

I did create the certificate with a password, but nginx is asking for it when I restart it via `nginx -s reload`. To temporarily solve this I wrote the password in a file and added this line to my `nginx.conf`:

```
ssl_password_file       /etc/nginx/pass;
```

Is there any way that I can avoid writing the password in a file?

Comment: Please have  a look at the nginx error log for what might be wrong. If you don't understand the messages there please add these to the question.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and I'd expect it to be covered on serverfault or superuser or maybe security.SX but I can't find a good dupe. You can remove the password from an existing OpenSSL privatekey file with `openssl rsa <k1 >k2` or `openssl pkey <k1 >k2` . You could have _created_ the privatekey without password by adding `-nodes` on the `openssl req -new -x509 ...` command. Note it's the key that has the password not the certificate, although a server like nginx needs both so this distinction is less important.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else with this issue.. it can also happen if you have forgotten to add `ssl` to the listen directives. Chrome shows `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` whilst Firefox shows `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR`.

```
server {
     listen 443 ssl http2;
     listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note for myself :-d

The **default_server** configuration (with ssl or/and without ssl) is missing from one of the virtual host definitions, like this:

```
server {
     listen 80 default_server;
     listen 443 default_server;
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is often not related to the browser. In our case it was also not a configuration thing of nginx, but a wrong setting of the firewall. So logically, when I say that often has nothing to do with the browser, server-side and not client-side. Accordingly, it was not a proxy or VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the **PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR** in Firefox while running my Apache as well as Nginx servers and both times it was because I forgot to listen on port **443** inside my configuration.
Always double-check the ports.